# Nobody nogroup on ubuntu client with Solaris server

Tags: nfs, openindiana

I have an openIdiana server with ZFS and it has been shared with NFS on a ubuntu server (called server1) one year ago.
Now i am asked to shared it on a second ubuntu server (called server2).
So i have took the line in /etc/fstab from server 1 and add it in server2:

**192.168.1.22:mypool/data/.zfs/snapshot /mnt/zfs   nfs     acl,intr,noatime        0       0**

But when i mount it, the rights on server2 are "nobody nogroup" (connect as anonymous?!) whereas its ok on server1.
And on my OpenIndiana, I haven't found where it is configured (its not me who configured it last year).
So I have tried to set **zfs set sharenfs=rw numpool/data** but without success. So i am looking for a file like /etc/exports on Ubuntu to configure which server is allowed to connect, and not as anonymous.
Any idea?

thanks,

Comment: Just add nfsvers=3 in fstab on the client!